# Turbo frame rule Response has no matching <turbo-frame id="name_of_the_frame">

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, turbo-frames

i am unable to reproduce turbo-frame error "Response has no matching " in my rails 7 application

index.html.erb

```
<main class="container">
  <%= turbo_frame_tag "first_turbo_frame" do %>
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Quotes</h1>
      <%= link_to "New quote",
                new_quote_path,
                class: "btn btn--primary" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= render @quotes %>
</main>
```

new.html.erb

```
<main class="container">
  <%= link_to sanitize("&larr; Back to quotes"), quotes_path %>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>New quote</h1>
  </div>
  <%= turbo_frame_tag "diff_frame" do %>
    <%= render "form", quote: @quote %>
  <% end %>
</main>
```

so according to turbo-frame rule when i try to create a new quote i will recieve 'no matching frame' error but in my case just page is refreshing with logging any error

i am following this https://www.hotrails.dev/turbo-rails/ to create quote application

Comment: Make sure that you are looking for the `has no matching <turbo-frame id="name_of_the_frame">` error in your browser inspect console and not rails logs.

Comment: Yes, that is where I am looking